# Escape full stops in dynamic column names mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js

```
const newDb = "dbtest";
const columns = ["test.TABLE"];
for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
  const column = `${columns[i]}_new`;
  console.log(require("mysql").format("SELECT * FROM ??.??",[newDb, column]));
}
```

how to make the string be ? `dbtest`.`test.TABLE` rather than `dbtest`.`test`.`table`

how to keep the . ?

the mysql formatter splits this badly, is this possible while still using the prepared statement?

Answer (score 0):

You can use punctuation or other symbols in your identifiers if you delimit them with back-ticks:

```
SELECT * FROM `??`.`??`
```

I would have thought the string-replacement node.js does should handle that delimiting already. Maybe you need to tell node.js that you're using the MySQL flavor of SQL?

Personally, I would just avoid naming tables with punctuation. Or use `_` because that doesn't need any special treatment.